# Google Assistant not properly answering questions about people's age or birth date (foreign names misheard)

Tags: voice-recognition, accessibility, google-assistant, date-and-time, google-voice-actions

I am running Android 11 on a Realme 8 5G phone. I would like Google Assistant to answer basic questions about people's age and birth dates, including my own.

I don't understand why it doesn't do this. When more than one user is present on the phone, it should recognize the person speaking on the basis of the voice being used, and answer the question (even providing more than one answer if it cannot disambiguate between voices).

Questions such as:

"What is my age?"

"When is my birthday/birth date"?

"How old is X?" (it should retrieve this information from the Contacts app).

"When is X's birthday/birth date?"

It is not uncommon for people who get older or develop some learning disability or dementia or other mind problem or who are simply lazy or forgetful to not be able to subtract the date of birth from the current date to compute their age.

The same goes for other people's data. A feature was introduced at some point where you could define kinship in the Contrats app and then just say "call mom/mum". This is also an Accessibility feature. But it would be just as useful if Google Assistant could answer "What is mom's/mum's age?".

Why is this important accessibility feature missing from Google Assistant?

When will it be added?

Is anyone willing to add it?

It would be highly appreciated.

(Here are some screenshots that display for Google Assistant is currently failing when I address the issue in Italian):

[image: Assistant 1]

[image: Assistant 2]

[image: Assistant 3]

UPDATE;

Perhaps this is just a flaw of Google Assistant in Italian. Perhaps, it does not work very well in other languages. Ad a matter of fact, it does not understand correctly non English names. For instance, when I ask Google Assistant, how old is Imma Bonuomo, an Italian name for one of my contacts, Google Assistant does not understand the mixed English and Italian speech (wouldn't it make sense that it did, looking in my contacts first, and, only then, searching on the web? It could even ask me "sounds I look in your contacts?",0 if it was unsure. Or alternatively, it could ask, back, "Search from contacts, or search from the web?", (not sure if Google Assistant has access to any other data sets, then these two places. Perhaps other apps may make data available though a content provider. Or, perhaps, it could ask, back, "Imma Bonuomo found in contacts. Use this result?" and you could specify back, "search the web", if that is not what you wanted. A list of other places to retrieve the data associated with or computed from the name, could be specified in the horizontal scrollable area of Google Assistant.

In any case, Google Assistant hears "Emma Barnett" instead of "Imma Bonuomo", and fails (with the result given in the image below).

Indeed, it gives me this result, when I run such search:

[image: wrong person result from Google Assistant]

Why is Google Assistant giving me this wrong result?

Thank you for any contributed improvements to Google Assistant.

And thank you for your answers.

UPDATE: I had placed the birth date in the notes, rather than in a separate field (due to a complication where two birth dates were existing separately for this person (the real birth date, and the one recorded at the registry office. Google Assistant was unable to search the notes field for this contract and find the birth date using DeepL (or something similar).

Thanks.

In any case, after reinserting the contact's information in the birthday field instead of in the notes field, the Italian counterpart answers properly to "quando è nata Imma" and "quanti anni ha Imma" (but the English counterpart still mishears). But when asking "how old am I?" In English, it works, but in Italian, "quanti anni ho io", which, is the same thing, doesn't work.

Thanks you for your contributed improvements.

Thank you for your answers.

Thanks.